# Android. HTTP requests take stupidly long time

Tags: android, kotlin, http, web-scraping

I'm writing a simple scraper app, which will let its users download books from a polish public-domain book site and I'm using `skrape.it` library for it. For some reason every HTTP requests takes more than 1 minute (!). I've tested it with cURL and the get time is consistently around 5 seconds.

```kotlin
    override suspend fun searchDocuments(query: String): List<DocumentInfo> {
        return skrape(AsyncFetcher) {
            request {
                url = "https://wolnelektury.pl/szukaj/?q=$query"
                timeout = 60000 * 2
            }
         ...
```

I'm calling it inside of viewModel

```kotlin
class DocumentsViewModel : ViewModel() {

    private var selectedRepository : DocumentRepository by mutableStateOf(DocerRepository())
    private var _documents : MutableStateFlow<List<DocumentInfo>?> = MutableStateFlow(null)
    val documents = _documents.asStateFlow()

    fun search(){
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            _documents.value = selectedRepository.searchDocuments(searchText)
        }
    }
}
```

When I set the timeout to a value lower than 2 minutes (or more) the app fails with this error

```
io.ktor.network.sockets.SocketTimeoutException: Socket timeout has expired [url=https://wolnelektury.pl/szukaj/?q=noc, socket_timeout=20000] ms
                                                                                                        at io.ktor.client.features.HttpTimeoutKt.SocketTimeoutException(HttpTimeout.kt:207)
                                                                                                        at io.ktor.client.engine.apache.ApacheHttpRequestKt.mapCause(ApacheHttpRequest.kt:62)
                                                                                                        at io.ktor.client.engine.apache.ApacheResponseConsumer.failed(ApacheResponseConsumer.kt:73)
                                                                                                        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.DefaultClientExchangeHandlerImpl.executionFailed(DefaultClientExchangeHandlerImpl.java:99)
                                                                                                        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.AbstractClientExchangeHandler.failed(AbstractClientExchangeHandler.java:426)
                                                                                                        at org.apache.http.nio.protocol.HttpAsyncRequestExecutor.timeout(HttpAsyncRequestExecutor.java:387)
                                                                                                        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.InternalIODispatch.onTimeout(InternalIODispatch.java:92)
```

And no, it's not just that site. I've tested it with a lot of different sites and it fails consistently when timeout < 120000

Comment: `url = "https://wolnelektury.pl/szukaj/?q=$query"` That does not very much look like an `http` request.

Comment: @blackapps what do you mean?

Comment: Well look at the used protocol: https is not http.

Comment: @blackapps I see, yes. But that's not the cause of the problem. The [library's website](https://docs.skrape.it/docs/http-client/request-options) shows an example with `url = "https://..."` so https should be supported. Are you pointing out that the question's title is misleading because it says "http"?

Comment: Not only in the title but also in your post.

Comment: It's not misleading as HTTPS is actually HTTP + SSL, so it's still HTTP. Besides, it's became a norm to use HTTP/HTTPS interchangeably these days